# GAN Training sees Generator Loss go to Zero While Producing Random Images

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network, unsupervised-learning, image-generation

I have a dataset of images on which I am trying to train a GAN to create something similar. I have looked at various tutorials for how to train a GAN but am still getting random outputs from my generator despite the loss converging to zero during training. I have included my generator and discriminator code below:

```
def make_discriminator_model():

    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Input((128, 128, 3)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (4,4), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (4,4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation=layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (4,4), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (4,4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation=layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))


    return model

discriminator = make_discriminator_model()

def make_generator_model():

    model = tf.keras.Sequential()

    model.add(layers.Dense(16*16*128, input_dim=512, activation=layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Reshape((16, 16, 128)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation=layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation=layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation=layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(3, (4,4), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='tanh'))


    return model

generator = make_generator_model()
```

My images are 128x128, with pixel values normalized to the range -1 to 1 so the output of the generator (tanh activation) matches the images being fed into the discriminator.

I have a custom `train_step` to train the model which I have included below inside my GAN class:

```
class GAN(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, generator, discriminator, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pass through args and kwargs to base class
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Create attributes for gen and disc
        self.generator = generator
        self.discriminator = discriminator

    def compile(self, g_opt, d_opt, g_loss, d_loss, *args, **kwargs):
        # Compile with base class
        super().compile(*args, **kwargs)

        # Create attributes for losses and optimizers
        self.g_opt = g_opt
        self.d_opt = d_opt
        self.g_loss = g_loss
        self.d_loss = d_loss

    def train_step(self, batch):
        # Get the data
        real_images = batch
        fake_images = self.generator(tf.random.normal((128, 512, 1)), training=False)

        # Train the discriminator
        with tf.GradientTape() as d_tape:
            # Pass the real and fake images to the discriminator model
            yhat_real = self.discriminator(real_images, training=True)
            yhat_fake = self.discriminator(fake_images, training=True)
            yhat_realfake = tf.concat([yhat_real, yhat_fake], axis=0)

            # Create labels for real and fakes images
            y_realfake = tf.concat([tf.ones_like(yhat_real), tf.zeros_like(yhat_fake)], axis=0)
            noise_real = -0.15*tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(yhat_real))
            noise_fake = 0.15*tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(yhat_fake))
            y_realfake += tf.concat([noise_real, noise_fake], axis=0)

            # Calculate loss - BINARYCROSS
            total_d_loss = self.d_loss(y_realfake, yhat_realfake)

        # Apply backpropagation - nn learn
        dgrad = d_tape.gradient(total_d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_variables)
        self.d_opt.apply_gradients(zip(dgrad, self.discriminator.trainable_variables))

        # Train the generator
        with tf.GradientTape() as g_tape:
            # Generate some new images
            gen_images = self.generator(tf.random.normal((128,512,1)), training=True)

            # Create the predicted labels
            predicted_labels = self.discriminator(gen_images, training=False)

            # Calculate loss - trick to training to fake out the discriminator
            total_g_loss = self.g_loss(tf.ones_like(predicted_labels), predicted_labels)

        # Apply backprop
        ggrad = g_tape.gradient(total_g_loss, self.generator.trainable_variables)
        self.g_opt.apply_gradients(zip(ggrad, self.generator.trainable_variables))

        return {"d_loss":total_d_loss, "g_loss":total_g_loss}

g_opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
d_opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001)
g_loss = BinaryCrossentropy()
d_loss = BinaryCrossentropy()
gan = GAN(generator, discriminator)

gan.compile(g_opt, d_opt, g_loss, d_loss)
```

I followed various tip and tricks taken from the following Github repository:

https://github.com/soumith/ganhacks

I have taken and edited a sublcass from the following repository after watching a tutorial:

https://github.com/nicknochnack/GANBasics/blob/main/FashionGAN-Tutorial.ipynb

I have trained the GAN for up to 300 epochs with random images still being output from the generator. I am not sure whether there is an issue with my loss function in the `train_step` ? The values for the output of the generator appear to be quite small and do not appear to be values anywhere close to the real images so I am not sure whether my generator layers may be doing something I am unaware of?

I did separately try to train the discriminator on real and random images and can see that alone (without any generator loss to consider), this model is training and making sensible predictions. During GAN training, the discriminator loss drops before flattening out at a low value.

My question is why would my generator not be training?

- Can it be the loss function `total_g_loss`?
- Are the hidden layers of the generator too complex / simple for image generation?

Any other tips to debug this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your total_g_loss definition, is there a reason you used tf.ones_like instead of tf.zeros_like?

Comment: so my discriminator is trying to predict real images (target = 1) so my understanding is that the loss for the GAN must consider the 1 - loss of the discriminator, ie fake images are labelled as 1 as opposed to zero. In the GANhacks link I provided, the following is given: 
Flip labels when training generator: real = fake, fake = real

Comment: What does the loss of your generator look like as it is training? Is it increasing, decreasing, converging?

Comment: As mentioned in the original question, my generator loss is coming down rapidly after only a couple of epochs and then converging to zero.